# When testing my NancyFX website which uses JWT Bearer Authentication, should I mock the CurrentUser or add an Authorize Header?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, jwt, nancy

I'm trying to test a .NET NancyFX website which is using JWT Bearer token for authorization.

Right now, I'm faking up the `context.CurrentUser` property (which works, mind you).

```
return new Browser(with =>
{ 
    with.Module<FooModule>();

    with.RequestStartup((container,
                         pipelines,
                         context) =>
    {
        context.CurrentUser = new UserIdentity(new User("Leia"));
    });

    // <snip the rest>
}
```

But I was wondering if this isn't really a proper way to be testing my end-to-end route? Should I be doing this instead .. and if so, how do I wire up whatever I need to wire up?

eg..

```
browser.Get("/",
            with =>
            {
                with.HttpsRequest();
                with.Header("Authorize", "Bearer BLAH");
            });
```

Suggestions, kind people?

Comment: I think both options are fine, the question is, is if you send a header with a predefined token which I assume you know will be validated will your JWT decoding take place as part of the test? ie/will it act as if it were a live system?

Comment: I guess that's the heart of the question: should i be using the `Authorize` header which does a _full_ end to end vs `CurrentUser` which skips the header check which means it might not be working 100%. I'm not sure of what other people are doing and why..

Answer (score 1):

Test the header decoding/receipt, don't fake context unless its a burden (it shouldn't be as its common to all (un)authorised tests).

Personally I minimise the number of calls I make to "new Browser() + browser.Method()" as this takes a while to initialise for each test. Depending on your modules it can take 400ms+, slow for unit tests. The reason for this is the reflection that Nancyfx performs to enumerate the nancyfx modules in binaries in the same directory.

Therefore if I have to test using the nancyfx browser, I make sure to test as much of what the route does as I can. If it requires a bearer, I pass that to enact the bearer auth code. I will however mock the database interaction, which in my case uses IDatabase.

If you want to test that your header decoding is working, test that in a separate set of unit tests. They will be faster, and more contained.